Mathematical expression parser for Java
Are there Java libraries that can evaluate string expressions like "5+4*3" into a decimal number (or an integer, if there's no decimal part)? I could parse it myself, but then I'd also have to take the operator precedence into account which would complicate things
I have been writing a Swing calculator, mainly as a way to practice using IntelliJ IDEA's GUI Designer (discovered it only recently). I don't need anything fancy. As long as it supports the basic addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication, I'm fine with it. The expression string may have parentheses too
public class DefaultCalcProcessor implements CalcProcessor {
    @Override
    public double calculateResult(String expression) {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}


I did a quick Google search and found some candidates for your problem:

Math Expression Evaluator
ExpressionOasis
MxParser
formula4j

To me, probably the latter three seem to match your needs. Though, I haven't tested any myself.
